# .then triggering before promise resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I am writing integration tests in Node with mocha and supertest and have to create users in the db. My problem is that sometimes the users get saved after the test completes.
This is my user creation function:

```
async function createUser() {
  const userParam = {
    username: "User",
    password: "123456789",
    firstName: "Max",
    lastName: "Mustermann",
    role: JSON.stringify(Role.User),
  };
  const user = new User(userParam);

  user.hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userParam.password, 10);

  await user.save();
  console.log("User saved!");
}
```

And this is the test:

```
it("respond with 403 forbidden, because a standard user cant delete other users", function (done) {
        createUser().then(
          login(userLoginData).then((responseBody) => {
            request(app)
              .delete("/users/0000000000006204aefc242c")
              .set(
                "Authorization",
                `Bearer ${responseBody.body.accessToken}`,
              )
              .expect(
                403,
                {
                  Error: "Forbidden",
                  message:
                    "Forbidden for your rank, if its not your own account.",
                },
                done,
              );
          }),
        );
      });
```

And this is the output i get from mocha:

```
  DELETE /
          Successes
    Admin saved!
    User saved!
          ✓ respond with 200 ok, because admins are allowed to delete all users (431ms)
    User saved!
          ✓ respond with 200 ok, because he is allowed to delete himself (195ms)
          Errors
            1) respond with 403 forbidden, because a standard user cant delete other users
    User saved!
```

The first two tests are completing because the needed accounts are created before the test, but the last test(which is shown above) fails.

Here is a link to the file in the current github branch:
https://github.com/Knniff/loginbackend/blob/2fa/test/tests.js

I would be glad about all feedback and if you have a better way of doing these kinds of preparations i would like to hear about it.

Comment: `then` doesn't trigger the callback too early - you're not passing a callback function!

Comment: so i should i have use return for the .save instead of await?

Comment: No, that's totally fine, your `createUser` function works. What doesn't work is the `.then(login(userLoginData).then(…))` in the test, where the `login` call should have been placed in a function expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in at the 2nd line in your test. You don't wait for promise to resolve and call `login()` function immediately after `createUser()` function. You should wrap a `login()` function call into an arrow function `() => login(userLoginData)`.
You can make the following changes to the test:

```
      it("respond with 403 forbidden, because a standard user cant delete other users", function (done) {
        createUser()
          .then(() => login(userLoginData))
          .then((responseBody) => {
            request(app)
              .delete("/users/0000000000006204aefc242c")
              .set(
                "Authorization",
                `Bearer ${responseBody.body.accessToken}`,
              )
              .expect(
                403,
                {
                  Error: "Forbidden",
                  message:
                    "Forbidden for your rank, if its not your own account.",
                },
                done,
              );
          });
      });
```

Edit:

Also, I suggest to use async/await in your tests:

```
it("respond with 403 forbidden, because a standard user cant delete other users", async function () {
  await createUser();
  const responseBody = await login(userLoginData);
  await request(app)
    .delete("/users/0000000000006204aefc242c")
    .set(
       "Authorization",
       `Bearer ${responseBody.body.accessToken}`,
    )
    .expect(
       403,
       {
         Error: "Forbidden",
         message: "Forbidden for your rank, if its not your own account."
       }
    );
 
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried the async wait route before but tried to mix it with done so i got nowhere. I got it working flawlessly now.